# Django Rest Framework & Entity–attribute–value model (EAV) Data Model

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, entity-attribute-value

```python
from django.db import models

# django user
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Entity(models.Model):
    """
    Entity of EAV
    """
    entity = models.CharField(max_length=216,
                            null=False, default='entity_name',
                            name='entity', verbose_name='Entity of EAV',
                            db_index=True,
                            unique=True
                            )


class Asset(models.Model):
    """
    Asset of EAV
    """
    asset = models.CharField(max_length=216, null=False,
                            default='asset', name='asset',
                            verbose_name='Asset of EAV'
                            )
    entity = models.ForeignKey(to=Entity)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("asset", "entity")


class Value(models.Model):
    """
    Value of EAV
    """
    value = models.CharField(max_length=216,
                             null=False, default='value',
                             name='value', verbose_name='Value of EAV'
                             )
    asset = models.ForeignKey(to=Asset)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='EAV Owner', related_name='eav')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('value', 'asset', 'owner')
```

**Serializers**

```python
class EntitySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
    entity = serializers.CharField(label='Entity of EAV', max_length=216, required=False)


class AssetSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
    asset = serializers.CharField(default='asset', label='Asset of EAV', max_length=216)
    entity = EntitySerializer(read_only=True)


class ValueSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
    value = serializers.CharField(default='value', label='Value of EAV', max_length=216)
    asset = AssetSerializer(read_only=True)
    owner = UserModelSerializer(read_only=True)


class EntityAssetValueSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    entity = EntitySerializer(many=True)
    asset = AssetSerializer(many=True)
    value = ValueSerializer(many=True)
```

**Expected Serialization**

```js
{
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "Hero",
      "id": 1,
      "owner": {
        "name": "BatMan",
        "id": "1"
      },
      "groups": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "SuperHeroes Group"
        }
      ],
      "asset": [
        {
          "asset": "Name",
          "value": "BatMan",
          "asset_id": 1,
          "value_id": 1
        },
        {
          "asset": "Age",
          "value": "30",
          "asset_id": 1,
          "value_id": 2
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "entity": "Hero",
      "id": 1,
      "owner": {
        "name": "SuperMan",
        "id": "2"
      },
      "groups": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "SuperHeroes Group"
        }
      ],
      "asset": [
        {
          "asset": "Name",
          "value": "SuperMan",
          "asset_id": 1,
          "value_id": 3
        },
        {
          "asset": "Age",
          "value": "30",
          "asset_id": 1,
          "value_id": 4
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "entity": "Villian",
      "id": 1,
      "owner": {
        "name": "Joker",
        "id": "3"
      },
      "groups": [
        {
          "id": "2",
          "name": "SuperVillians Group"
        }
      ],
      "asset": [
        {
          "asset": "Name",
          "value": "Joker",
          "asset_id": 3,
          "value_id": 4
        },
        {
          "asset": "Age",
          "value": "30",
          "asset_id": 4,
          "value_id": 5
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "entity": "Person",
      "id": 1,
      "owner": {
        "name": "Puny Human",
        "id": "3"
      },
      "groups": [
        {
          "id": "2",
          "name": "Humans Group"
        }
      ],
      "asset": [
        {
          "asset": "Name",
          "value": "Human Being",
          "asset_id": 5,
          "value_id": 6
        },
        {
          "asset": "Age",
          "value": "30",
          "asset_id": 6,
          "value_id": 7
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Achieved Serialization**

```js
{
  "eav": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "value": "Human",
      "asset": {
        "id": 1,
        "asset": "Name",
        "entity": {
          "id": 1,
          "entity": "Human"
        }
      },
      "owner": {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "PunyHuman"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "value": "26",
      "asset": {
        "id": 2,
        "asset": "Age",
        "entity": {
          "id": 1,
          "entity": "Human"
        }
      },
      "owner": {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "PunyHuman"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "value": "26",
      "asset": {
        "id": 3,
        "asset": "Age",
        "entity": {
          "id": 2,
          "entity": "Hero"
        }
      },
      "owner": {
        "id": 2,
        "username": "BatMan"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "value": "BatMan",
      "asset": {
        "id": 3,
        "asset": "Name",
        "entity": {
          "id": 2,
          "entity": "Hero"
        }
      },
      "owner": {
        "id": 2,
        "username": "BatMan"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "value": "26",
      "asset": {
        "id": 3,
        "asset": "Age",
        "entity": {
          "id": 2,
          "entity": "Hero"
        }
      },
      "owner": {
        "id": 3,
        "username": "SuperMan"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "value": "SuperMan",
      "asset": {
        "id": 4,
        "asset": "Name",
        "entity": {
          "id": 2,
          "entity": "Hero"
        }
      },
      "owner": {
        "id": 3,
        "username": "SuperMan"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**API View**

```python
class EntityAssetValueAPIView(APIView):

    queryset = Value.objects.select_related('asset', 'asset__entity', 'owner')
    serializer_class = ValueSerializer

    # If you want to use object lookups other than pk, set 'lookup_field'.
    # For more complex lookup requirements override `get_object()`.
    lookup_field = 'pk'
    # lookup_url_kwarg = None

    # The filter backend classes to use for queryset filtering
    # filter_backends = api_settings.DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS

    # The style to use for queryset pagination.
    # pagination_class = api_settings.DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS
    # def allowed_methods(self):
    #     http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'patch', 'delete', 'head', 'options', 'trace']
    #     return http_method_names
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        eav = self.queryset.all()
        serializer = self.serializer_class(eav, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

What I want to do is, Get all the ENTITIES Assigned to a USER ( along with the ASSET & VALUES ).

The same data is posted for a NEW ENTITY ASSIGNMENT to USER .

From What I understood from DRF, I would need an API view, API view would call serializer, so, I would have to create a custom Serializer, then to save the data I have to override `create` method, where in I will have these separate serializers that would validate the data and save it.

I am not able to send the desired RESPONSE or ingest the REQUEST coming in.

What should be a way forward ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the similar problem So I'll explain a little scenario here. So you can take reference from that.

Added some related names in models :

```
class Asset(models.Model):
    """
    Asset of EAV
    """
    asset = models.CharField(max_length=216, null=False,
                            default='asset', name='asset',
                            verbose_name='Asset of EAV'
                            )
    entity = models.ForeignKey(to=Entity, related_name='asset_entity')

class Value(models.Model):
    """
    Value of EAV
    """
    value = models.CharField(max_length=216,
                             null=False, default='value',
                             name='value', verbose_name='Value of EAV'
                             )
    asset = models.ForeignKey(to=Asset, related_name='asset_value')
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='EAV Owner', related_name='eav')
```

initial queryset looks like this, the idea is to fetch all information that is required initially:

```
 queryset = Entity.objects.filter('**condition comes here**')
                .values('id', 'entity', 'asset_entity', 'asset_entity__asset', 'asset_entity__asset_value', 'asset_entity__asset_value__value',
                    'asset_entity__asset_value__owner_id',)
```

Pass this queryset when trying to make response :

```
serializer = serializer(queryset, many=True, context={'request': request})
```

**Serailizers :**

```
class Owner_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)

        class Meta:
            model = User
            exclude = ('**exclude fields you want to exclude**', )


class EntitySerializer(serializers.Serializer):

        id = serializers.IntegerField(source='id')
        entity = serializers.CharField(source='entity')
        owner =  serializers.SerializerMethodField()
        groups =  serializers.SerializerMethodField()
        asset =  serializers.SerializerMethodField()


        def get_owner(self, obj):
            return Owner_Serializer(obj.get('asset_entity__asset_value__owner_id'), context=self.context).data
```

Same process goes for groups and asset fields.

in `get_owner()` we have `entity object` and from that object we can get `owner_id` , as we have already fetched related data initially.

So the main idea here to fetch all data initially and then serilaize that data according to your requirement.

Existing Nested Serailization do not support the response format you required.

Note : Initial querset is vry important , you may need to use prefetch related there because we are fetching data using reverse relationship. Also I didn't test the queryset so have to make sure that correct related_names are used to fetch related data.